# How to insert custom php into a specific html code (acf field / wordpress)?

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I need to insert the following custom php code inside the existing HTML code (under the p tag).
Would you please let me know how to add it?
I'm a newbie, any comments would be a big help.


PHP code:

```
$myvalue = get_field( "field_60f5d9a279544" ); 
echo do_shortcode($myvalue);
```

Existing code (created using acf / frontend):

```
<div class="acf-field acf-field-textarea acf-field-60po7a8eu9333 elementor-repeater-item-b95d154" data-name="rtype_selection_desc" data-type="textarea" data-key="field_60po7a8eu9333">
<div class="acf-label">
<label for="acf-field_60po7a8eu9333">Enter Info</label></div>
<div class="acf-input">
<p class="description">Search and Enter Info</p>
*****how to add the php code here?*****
<textarea id="acf-field_60po7a8eu9333" name="acf[field_60po7a8eu9333]" rows="8"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: for simple solution use shortcode to add specific page instead of template, there is [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) and easy guide to use.

Comment: Or if you have existing code, try other like
[your_shortcode variable="<?php echo $myvalue; ?>"]

Comment: Hi: Thank you for your help. I have a shortcode [ajaxdomainchecker] and I looked into the link you shared, but I couldn't find how to add the shortcode to the specific html element. Would you please let me know how to code it? Thank you.

Comment: does it not work insert the shortcode directly?

Comment: Hi Rach: no... I got an idea from you and I tried it but it doen't work, so I added the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448846/how-to-insert-a-shortcode-to-an-existing-html-elements-wordpress