# How can I insert a shortcode to an existing HTML elements (WordPress)?

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress

I need to insert a shortcode `[ajaxdomainchecker]` into existing HTML code.

I tried the following code but it shows error. Would you please let me know how to add the shortcode?

##### Error *SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier*

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var sessionName = '<?php echo do_shortcode("[ajaxdomainchecker]"); ?>';
        jQuery(" .acf-field-60po7a8eu9444 p.description").html(sessionName);
    });
</script>
```

##### Error *SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list*

```
jQuery(' .acf-field-60po7a8eu9444 p.description').html('<?php echo do_shortcode("[ajaxdomainchecker]"); ?>');
```

##### Error *SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token*

```
jQuery(" .acf-field-60po7a8eu9444 p.description").html("<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajaxdomainchecker]'); ?>");
```

##### *SyntaxError: Unexpected token*

```
jQuery('.acf-field-60f5d9a279544 p.description').html(<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajaxdomainchecker]'); ?>);
```

##### Existing code (created using `acf/frontend`):

```html
<div class="acf-field acf-field-textarea acf-field-60po7a8eu9444 elementor-repeater-item-b95d154" data-name="rtype_selection_desc" data-type="textarea" data-key="field_60po7a8eu9444">
    <div class="acf-label">
        <label for="acf-field_60po7a8eu9444">Enter Info</label>
    </div>
    <div class="acf-input">
        <p class="description">Search and Enter Info</p>
        <!-- how to add the short code here? -->
        <textarea id="acf-field_60po7a8eu9444" name="acf[field_60po7a8eu9444]" rows="8"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: isbe, a shortcode cannot be meaningfully inserted AFTER the php code has run.  It needs to be in the html code that is stored in the db.  When wordpress generates the html for the page content it basically does a text replace - swopping the [shortcode] for the output returned by the shortcode handler function.

Comment: Hi anmari: ah, I see, thank you for your comments. I removed :after and tried it again, but still shows the same error. Would you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the shortcode in your post where you enter the data in ACF input. And set your shortcode as a default value to that field.
"Make a search and enter info" label as another ACF field that helps you change the text of the label whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea with the do_shortcode() command, but you can just put it right into your PHP file like so:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[ajaxdomainchecker]"); ?>
```

Comment: Hi : Thank you for your comment. I need to put the shortcode in an existing html elements (between p and textarea that was crated using an acf. Could you help me how to add it to the place? Thank you.

Comment: Then you would place it in a Shortcode block as it is made to do. Those are your two options. jQuery won't help you here. https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-a-shortcode-in-wordpress/

Comment: Or a WYSIWIG block if that is available

Comment: Hi Jons: I tried it, but it shows a text [ajaxdomainchecker] instead of loading the shortcode... https://i.imgur.com/bh2ZnDY.jpg Is there any solution for this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Can you just edit the PHP file under Theme Editor?

Comment: The page is a single post theme, and the acf is for frontend. When I load the fild it just loads the entire fields. So I can't edit it directly. I am trying to find workaround...